# Prolog - can I find all cases which would make a predicate true?

Tags: prolog

If I have two rules like this:

```
hasproperty(X, wet) :- hasproperty(X, was_in_rain).
hasproperty(X, wet) :- hasproperty(X, washed).
```

How can I ask - which properties X might have, so that it is wet.
In the example what I want to get is: was_in_rain and washed.

12 Sep. clarification: I'm not interested in finding all Xs which have the property of being wet. Imagine that there is no further rules or facts defined. 
What I'm interested in:
give me possible Y in hasproperty(X, Y), from which through the prolog rules you can infer hasproperty(X, wet).
The result in the given example would be Y=was_in_rain and Y=washed

Basically, I wonder if it is possible to have queries which would analyse the rules themselves.

Comment: To ask what `X` is wet, you just enter the query, `hasproperty(X, wet).` and Prolog should provide you the possible solutions for `X`. For this to succeed with solutions, you need to have some facts or rules that provide `X` such that `hasproperty(X, was_in_rain)` is true or `hasproperty(X, washed)` is true. I would also recommend that you name your rules differently than your facts. If you have a set of facts `hasproperty/2`, then it's recommended your rule be named something ther than `hasproperty`. Otherwise, as your facts and rules grow, you're more likely to get into some circular logic.

Comment: @lurker , thanks. I knew the first part, i.e. how it would work if I have a set of facts and rules, and how I can use them to find new set of facts. But, while it doesn't help me directly with my question, what I can conclude from your comment is the in Prolog you can't actually make a query through which you would examine the rules themselves. Is that fair to say?

Comment: I think you need an example to clarify your question. I thought I was responding to it directly. You can examine rules, but it's not clear to me exactly what you you want to query and what kind of results you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [findall/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) to find all solutions of a predicate. In this case, it appears that `hasproperty(X, wet)` is always false.

```
:- initialization(main).

main :-
    findall(X,hasproperty(X,wet),Z),
    writeln(Z). % there are no solutions, so Z is an empty list

hasproperty(X, wet) :- hasproperty(X, was_in_rain).
hasproperty(X, wet) :- hasproperty(X, washed).
```

Comment: thanks. I added clarification to explain better what I was asking for.